# If $u$ and $w$ belongs to the same connected components, does there exist any $u-w$ path containing $v$?

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

[image]

If $u$ and $w$ belongs to the same connected components, does there exist any $u-w$ path containing $v$?

Comment: What does it mean for two vertices to be in the same connected component?  That should be a definition in the book you're reading.

Comment: according toalgebrai anonymous answer,how can i guarantee that each path contain v? what happen if u and w lie in G1?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question until now.  The two vertices $u$ and $w$ are chosen to be in different components of $G-v$.  So they can't both be in $G_1$.

Comment: in the statement of the theorem it is given that there exist u, w of G distinct from v such that v is in every u-w path in G. what happen if u, w lies in the same connected components of G\v?

Comment: why did the author specifically write the underlined statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If $v$ is a cut vertex of $G$, then $G-v$ is disconnected and has at least two components , $G_1$ and $G_2$.  Take $u \in G_1$ and $w \in G_2$.

You ask, “what happens if $u$ and $w$ lie in the same connected component of $G-v$?”

If $u$ and $w$ were in the same component of $G-v$, let's say $G_1$, there would be a path in $G_1$ connecting $u$ to $w$.  This path would **not** contain $v$, because $G_1$ is a component of $G-v$.  It might happen that some paths in $G$ connecting $u$ to $w$ contain $v$, but not all of them.

But notice that $u$ and $w$ aren't arbitrary vertices—far from it.  We only need to show that such vertices exist somewhere in $G$.  So we carefully **require** that $u$ and $w$ come from different components of $G-v$.  Now we know there *is* a path connecting $u$ to $w$ in $G$ (because $G$ is connected), but there is *no* path connecting $u$ to $w$ in $G-v$ (because $G-v$ is not connected, and $u$ and $w$ are in different components), so every path from $u$ to $w$ in $G$ must not be a path in $G-v$.  That is, every  path from $u$ to $w$ in $G$ must contain $v$.

Answer (score 0):

Not in $G_1 \cup G_2$, since $v$ is contained neither in $G_1$ nor in $G_2$. Indeed, $G_1 \cup G_2 = G \setminus \{v\}$. However, there exists a path in $G$ because $G$ is connected.

Comment: how can i guarantee that each path contain v? what happen if u and w lie in G1?

Comment: Then v will not be a cut vertex, if u and w cannot be chosen to avoid that.

Comment: then why the theorem says like this there exist u and w such that v lies in every u-w path.